# MVC6, If user submit decimal / int value empty from view, server side model validation show wrong message

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core-mvc

MVC6,
There is issue found on model validation server side.

```
public string Genre { get; set; }
public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

If user submits decimal / int value empty from view, server side model validation shows wrong message i.e. the value "" is not valid.

I have checked in the controller, the incoming model is showing price value 0 as the default but ModelState getting rawValue="". So conflicting with datatype and throw msg.

model is carring 0 as default (even user submit with empty) so should validate with 0 not with "" (string.empty).

front javascript validation working fine but server side model validation shows wrong error message
as "the value "" is not valid"

decimal / int is always getting 0 as default value.

Any solution to resolve this?

Comment: Is this JavaScript? You may want to tag the appropriate languages in your question so it can get better visibility.

Comment: It's Microsoft's MVC framework (asp.net, c#)

Comment: asp.net core 1.0 mvc 6, model validation & binding related

Comment: Can you show your validation data annotations?

Answer (score 2):

you can add a validation region in your controller and validate it your self .

```
if (model.Price == 0)
   ModelState.AddModelError("", "please enter the price .");
   return View();
```

or if your ModelState.IsValid() is false you can tell the model state to prevent from validate that decimal/int field .
Add this code before your ModelState.IsValid()

```
ModelState.Remove("Price");
```

then add the value 0 to it your self .
or if price is a required field you can add data annotations attributes to add customized validation errors to it :

```
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter thye price .")]
public decimal price {get;set;}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem in my ASP Core project. Model validation was set for integers by using `Range` attribute and `Required` with errors message. But when user put into `input` control empty i get error message like

> "The value '' is invalid."

In model value was 0 but raw value was empty. I have to edit my model for nullable properties and use attributes. And i get result as i want.

```
[Range(1, int.MaxValue,ErrorMessage = "My message1")]
[Required (ErrorMessage = "My message2")]
public int? PreparationTimeMinutes { get; set; }
```

I hope someone will help.